# Learning APIs - Working with JSON to grab a video - Need assistance

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object, embed

thank you for reading my question. I am trying to learn how to use APIs, and of course that usually goes hand in hand with manipulating JSON data.

I want to get a simple grasp on this concept before I try more complicated things, so let's just say the response from a request is:

```
{
  "embed": {
    "code": "<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"></iframe>"
   }
}
```

My next best guess would be 1) throw quotes around the above code, 2) assign it to, and declare it as a variable, let's say "var data" 3) declare another variable for the parsed JSON data:

```
var solu = JSON.parse(data);
```

but beyond that, I have had real difficulty accessing elements of the object. If this sounds confusing to you, I apologize. Please let me know if I am approaching this from the wrong angle.

Comment: `let's just say the response from a request is` - if that is a TEXT response, then you'll have a hard time parsing it because of the `"` characters in the "code" value. I doubt you'll get much help - your question is way too broad for anyone to give good answers

Comment: thanks for the input Jaromanda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use `JSON.parse(data)` as you are already using a json object.

```js
var data = {
  "embed": {
    "code": '<iframe src="https: //www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"></iframe>'.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  },
  // keys can be wrapped with string or not
  key: 'got the key',
  'stringKey': 'got the string identifier',
  'key with spaces': 'keys can have spaces or any reserved character',
  arrayOfStuff: ['thing', 'stuff', 'more']
}

// you can get data using the dot operator to nest deeper
console.log( data.embed );
// or use the array brackets syntax
console.log( data['embed'] );
// you can mix it up as both are equivelent, this will dig further into the object to code
console.log( data['embed'].code );
// if you key has reserved characters you must use the array bracket syntax
console.log( data['key with spaces'] );
// you can use arrays as well
console.log( data.arrayOfStuff[0] )
console.log( data['arrayOfStuff'][1] )
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for synthet1c!